# What platform(s) to use for developing an audio mixing web app?

Tags: audio, web, mixing

I am working on a browser-based application that is essentially a Digital Audio Workstation.  I've seen one out there (at http://www.indabamusic.com), and it looks like it is a Java applet.  Is a Java applet the best way to do this?

I've read that C++ is generally more widely used for audio programs, and I've looked at Wt ( http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/) for a web interface option but it doesn't seem to be meant for this kind of use (correct me if I'm wrong).

I have almost no experience with C++, so I might just be biased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want a java applet or to do it in Flash (perhaps Flex). It is generally messy to get C++ bits deployed broadly in a browser.